# How to implement iferror function in VBA MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I just want to ask: How can i implement "EXCEL" functions such as:

```
iferror
iserror
```

in VBA "WORD". I know how to do it in excel but not in word.

e.g. (excel)

```
application.worksheetfunction.iferror( ... )
```

but i am doing the code in MSWord. The above function doesn't seem to work.

Q1. Is it possible?

Q2. If yes, can you enlighten me on the code pattern?

I tried searching for google answers but all seem to point on excel method. Thank you so much..

Edit:

To elaborate my problem, i have a userform in Word that should collect numerical value and store in variable

> qty1, qty2 ... qty18, then uc1, uc2 ... uc18

so if I process the variables

```
If Me.qty1.Value * Me.uc1.Value <> 0 Then
    tot1 = Me.qty1.Value * Me.uc1.Value
Else
    tot1 = ""
End If
```

it gives me error:

> type mismatch

because when i leave qty2 to qty18 empty, it is understood as null string (?) just like in excel.

Are there any other way to do this?

Comment: Just use plain VBA - `If IsError(something) Then`  But it looks (after your edit) like you should first check the values of your inputs are numbers before feeding them into any calculations.

Comment: the excel application function is actually running a worksheet cell formula from VBA   .... your _type mismatch_ error is probably because `tot1` is defined as a numeric variable and you are assigning a string value to it ... or `tot1` is defined as a string variable and you are trying to assign a numeric value to it ..... when you have any questions about errors, please **say which line caused the error** (there is no way to guess sometime)

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, I checked my inputs before i start my calculations but it still gives me the same error. I tried the casual iferror but it seems I'm missing something here.

Comment: @jsotola, hello sir, I did change my tot1 declaration as string. Still gives me error. Can it be in the initial value of my userform?

Comment: you cannot do math functions on strings

Comment: @jsotola, i had my 'qty1.value' taken from user input in userform. Is it understood as string by default?

Comment: the line with error is the one with multiplication (*) in it.

Comment: ooops, thank you for correction @YowE3K. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Dim aaa As Double
Dim bbb As Double
Dim tot1 As Double

aaa = Me.qty1.Value
bbb = Me.uc1.Value

tot1 = 0

If IsNumeric(aaa) And IsNumeric(bbb) Then

    tot1 = Val(aaa) * Val(bbb)

end if
```

Comment: You should test that the values are numeric **before** trying to store them in variables of type `Double`.  (You probably meant `Dim aaa As String: Dim bbb As String`)

Comment: @jsotola, sorry i read your comment last. I tried to tinker also on my problem based on our discussion above. I came up with this: `dim tot1 as string:  If Me.qty1.Value = "" Or Me.uc1.Value = "" Then tot1 = "" else  tot1 = Me.qty1.Value * Me.uc1.Value`.. I am still on track?